# VSIX-Project: Unable to get current Workspace due to casting issues

Tags: c#, roslyn, workspace, vsix

I am trying to build a VSIX-package for vs2017 to make a customtool available.
The problem i am facing now is that i am unable to get the current workspace while debugging.
The following code is used to get the workspace:

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        var workspace = (Workspace)componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>();
```

The error thrown in the second line of code is "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.RoslynVisualStudioWorkspace' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace'.".

I already added the languageservices-package to the project as suggested on other threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen if you have two different versions of the Roslyn DLLs loaded (you can check that in Debug, Modules).

Make sure that the references to Roslyn in your VSIX project are not set to Copy Local or to Include in VSIX.

Comment: now i am getting closer to the issue. in modules i've seen that Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces was loaded 2 times so i excluded the reference in the vsix from output.

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version 2.3.0.0'.... " can i get this working with assembly-redirects ? i see the assembly is already loaded, just in a different version

Comment: @D.J.: Sounds like you're referencing a version of Roslyn newer than your VS build.  Either upgrade VS or downgrade Roslyn.

Comment: Specifically, VS' built-in binding redirects handle only up to VS' own version of Roslyn.

Comment: In my case I installed latest version of 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices' package (version 4.8) and it was newer than the one used by Visual Studio itself (version 4.7). Because of this I could see two .dll in Modules window. Downgrading package to 4.7 solved the issue.